# What is reason for syntax error of print statement of given python code

Tags: python, printing, syntax-error, concatenation

```
xString = input("Enter a number: ")
x = int(xString)
yString = input("Enter a second number: ")
y = int(yString)
print('The sum of ', x, ' and ', y, ' is ', x+y, '.', sep='')
```

on executing above code, interpretor throwing syntax error saying syntax error as below.

```
 print(?The sum of ?, x, ? and ?, y, ? is ?, sum, ?.?, sep=??)
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Replace strange quote symbol ’ by ' and try again your code.

Comment: Are those apostrophes? Use single or double quotes instead.

Comment: version: Python 2.5.2

Comment: @srikanthps: Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: I voted to close because the code has been edited, but the error message couldn't be that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single quote used in the print statement is `'` with ascii value 39.

```
>>> ord("'")
39
```

The one `’` used in the print statement in the question is not a quote `'` but [RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm)

```
>>> u"’"
u'\u2019'
```

---

Since, you are using python 2, to use `sep` in the print statement you need to *import the functionality from the future*.

```
from __future__ import print_function
print('The sum of ', x, ' and ', y, ' is ', x+y, '.', sep='')
```

Answer (score 5):

It's because of those wacky quote characters like `’`.  Change them to `'` characters and you should not have any problem.

Comment: I modified the statement as your suggestion, but still error persisting.     print('The sum of ', x, ' and ', y, ' is ', sum, '.', sep= '')

Answer (score 0):

First, replace the `’`  by `'`

Second, you may need to add one more sentence: `from __future__ import print_function`